# Binding.TargetUpdated not firring after initial form load

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

below i have a control template that comprises of two text box. The control template is used as a grid's cell display template and the datacontext is a bindinglist of my model object (which implement INotifyPropertyChanged).  The second text box is initially Collapsed.  However when "Ask" and "Bid" price updates happen, i want to 'flash" this text box by toggling visibility for about 1 second.

The problem i'm seeing is that on initial load of the form, i do see the 2nd text box flash, but after that...nothing. Interestingly if i click on a cell grid (which activates the edit template) then click out of the cell (which reverts back to the display template, which is the template shown below), the 2nd textbox then flashes.

Can anyone see an issue why the 2nd textbox would not 'flash' when AskPrice or BidPrice changes? I do see that the converter is being invoked as expected, but the update is not triggering the storyboard animation.

```
<Style x:Key="PriceSpreadAlertStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated" >
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.6" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.8" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01.2" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="QuoteDisplayTemplate" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding QuotePrice}" />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PriceSpreadAlertStyle}">
          <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AskBidToSpreadConverter}">
              <Binding Path="AskPrice" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" />
              <Binding Path="BidPrice" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" />
            </MultiBinding>
          </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that i found was to move 'NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True"' from the Binding element to the MultiBinding element.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see that its 'getting' your value in the code behind when you do a NotifyPropertyChanged.

For the same reason, check for any binding expression errors when you initially start up.

Also, you could try changing the binding modes to oneway, I didn't think so but they could be getting set to a onetime binding preventing it from handling the changed event.

EDIT:
Have you tried using the SourceUpdated RoutedEvent instead of the TargetUpdated?

Comment: it is getting the value in code behind.  in fact, i see the 2nd text box being updated with the correct value from the converter if make it always visible.  It just seems like the storyboard is not being triggered for some reason.