# Strange EventTrigger "OnLoad" behavior WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, triggers

I'm simulating a car videogame scoreboard that is constantly updated and sorted. Everything works as I expected but then I tryied to add an EventTrigger that makes an animation when the new drivers are inserted to my list and that made strange behaviours.

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
<!--...-->
</EventTrigger>
```

Sometimes when I fire that event in one car, it seems like more cars are suscripted to this event so that is not going as I expected. Obviously I would like every car had his own event. Moreover, that event is also fired when the scoreboard is sorted i.e when a car changes his position.

Now I'm going to explain what I have:

The following list is constantly updated (adds and update elements) and is not sorted by position because Im doing this directly on my view:

```
public ObservableCollection<Car> ListaObservable { get; set; }
```

The following code is extracted from the View:

```
<UserControl>

<UserControl.Resources> 

    <DataTemplate DataType="models:Car">
        <!-- Each grid represents a car that should shine everytime it passes through the finish line -->
        <Grid>
            <!--...-->
            <Grid.Triggers>

            <!-- Everytime "Estimacion" is updated, that event is fired as I expected -->

                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard >
                            <!-- It doesn't matter what kind of animation is -->
                            <Duration="{Binding Estimacion, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>         
                </EventTrigger>

<!-- The event I mentioned before is never fired when I add a new car to my list of Cars so I created that event but sometimes it does strange behaviours --> 
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <!-- ... -->
                    </BeginStoryBoard>
                </Eventrigger>
            </Grid.Triggers>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedItems" Source="{Binding ListaObservable}" IsLiveSortingRequested="True"> 
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions> 
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Posicion"/>     
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions> 
</CollectionViewSource>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedItems}}" BorderThickness="0" MinHeight="800" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Finally, In my case how can I fire an EventTrigger directly by my ViewModel?**

**How can I create a new event that can be fired everytime I want it?**

Comment: The Loaded event occurs because items should be disconnected from visual tree and conected again when they are moved. Probably the last answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868906/binding-targetupdated-not-firring-after-initial-form-load can help you.

Comment: If you want this event to be loaded when this `Window` or `UserControl` is loaded, why don't you fire it when it's loaded, instead of the `ListBox-Grid`? As you are firing this `loaded` inside a `ListBox`, maybe this listbox is being re-loaded more than supposed...

Comment: @Sonhja Thanks for your response. I don't want to refresh all the UserControl everytime the Listbox is changing.

Comment: But with what you are doing you are refreshing the whole `Grid`. In this case you only load the event once, when the  `UserControl` is loaded.

Comment: @Sonhja Im sorry but I don't understand you. Probably Im not clear explaining my problem it or I just have simplified my code too much. Let me make some changes. Thanks for your time.